# Import * as firebase from 'firebase/app' returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, next.js

I'm trying to use firebase v9 on my Next.js project, but whenever I import it it seems to be returning undefined...

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'

export function getFirebaseApp() {
  const clientCredentials = { ... }
  return firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials)
}
```

However, when I try to run this in the browser, all I get is this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined
```

This happens with any variation of the import, I've tried several:

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

// and the same thing importing from '@firebase/app' instead, though don't think that'd ever work
```

I really have no idea what is going on, I don't think this is an issue from Next.js because even VSCode doesn't suggest importing anything from firebase, even though it's installed (I can see it in `node_modules`). I have this line in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.0.2"
  }
}
```

So this is a mistery really, I really have no idea what is going on.
Any suggestions how I can fix this issue?

**EDIT**: Since I've gotten two comments suggesting this I guess I'll just put it here:

I am using the modular SDK, so I tried importing `initializeApp` directly, but it still did not work:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'

export function getFirebaseApp() {
  const clientCredentials = { ... }
  return initializeApp(clientCredentials)
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')
```

Comment: No, as I said in the post, I tried importing it as suggested in that answer (`import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';`) but got the same result

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Next server after changing to `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'` ? Make sure any other variation is commented out.

Comment: Just tried that, got the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initializeApp')` which I assume is the same thing, 'firebase/app' is still undefined

Comment: The syntax is `return initializeApp(clientCredentials)` and not `return firebase.initializeApp(clientCredentials)`

Comment: I know, I changed it to that when I got that error (otherwise it'd just tell me firebase is undefined).

Comment: I've now tried setting up the whole thing from scratch, and I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the `next` version of `firebaseui` and it will work with the new SDK:

```
npm i -S firebaseui@next
```

and integrate it in your app like [here](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/blob/master/packages/rmw-shell/src/containers/AuthUI/AuthUI.js).

You don't have the benefits of the new SDK if you use the `compat` version.

As said in the github issues both libs won't update soon so it would pay off to do this little effort and move 100% to the new SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the issue. I was using `react-firebaseui` - Unfortunately, it does not support the modular version of firebase (yet). So the solution is either to use something else, or use the compat library:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
```